# Tensorflow train.py throws Windows fatal exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I've been working with Tensorflow for quite a while now, had some issues, but they never remained unresolved. Today i wanted to train a new model, when things got interesting. At first, the training stopped after one step without any reason. It happend before, opening a new cmd window solved it. Not this time tough. After i tried again, train.py started to throw this:

> Windows fatal exception: access violation
>
> Current thread 0x000018d4 (most recent call first):
>
> File
>   "C:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
>   line 84 in _preread_check   File
>   "C:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
>   line 122 in read   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py",
>   line 133 in load_labelmap   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py",
>   line 164 in get_label_map_dict   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py",
>   line 59 in **init**   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py",
>   line 314 in **init**   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py",
>   line 130 in build   File "train.py", line 121 in get_next   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py",
>   line 59 in create_input_queue   File
>   "C:\Users\xx\source\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py",
>   line 280 in train   File "train.py", line 180 in main   File
>   "C:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 324 in new_func   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251 in
>   _run_main File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300 in
>   run File
>   "C:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
>   line 40 in run   File "train.py", line 184 in

Last time i saw this issue, it was because i was using data downloaded from the internet, and there was one particular picture that TF did not like, but removing that one from the dataset solved the issue. I was wondering if this was the case, but no. I couldnt start it with previously tried datasets either... i decided to reinstall tensorflow, set up a new virtual environment, but still nothing. Been looking for hours what the problem could be, both on the internet, and on my own trying different things, but nothing worked, same exception each time. Did anybody encounter anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to share what solved my problem, might help the others. I reinstalled Tensorflow itself in a virtual environment, and upgraded it to version 1.8 (Requires Python 3.6, it is not compatible with higher versions (mine is 3.6.5 in particular)), make sure your PYTHONPATH variable is pointing to the right folder. Also, on Windows, this error message on can occur when you use generate_tfrecord.py, i ran into it many times, it usually happend, because i had image(s), that Tensorflow did not like (i'm not completly sure about the cause), at first, try removing .webp, .gif, etc.(non .png/.jpg) files. I even had the exception for renaming an image downloaded from the internet, and TF did not stand it anymore.